# VBA error 424 object not found, but I have the object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA, but learning pretty quickly. I have this userform called AddRoute55 and a CommandButton inone of my sheets to activate it.

The code behind the **CommandButton** is:

```
Private Sub Route55Button_Click()

AddRoute55.Show

End Sub
```

**Where the userformcode is:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty Status
StatusBox.Clear

'Fill StatusBox
With StatusBox
    .AddItem "Received"
    .AddItem "Returned to PM"
    .AddItem "In Progress"
    .AddItem "On Hold"
    .AddItem "Complete"
    .AddItem "Closed"
    .AddItem "RFC"
End With


'Empty BTBox
BTBox.Clear

'Fill BTBox
With BTBox
    .AddItem "Run"
    .AddItem "Change"
End With

'Empty DomainBox
DomainBox.Clear

'Fill DomainBox
With DomainBox
    .AddItem "AMS NL"
    .AddItem "AMS INT"
    .AddItem "EUS"
    .AddItem "IPS"
    .AddItem "NGC"
    .AddItem "Office"
    .AddItem "SM"
End With

'Empty AIMSBox
AIMSBox.Value = ""

'Empty ProjectCoedeBox
ProjectCodeBox.Value = ""

'Empty PMBox
PMBox.Value = ""

'Empty POBox
POBox.Value = ""

'Empty VendorBox
VendorBox.Value = ""

'Set No FTR as default
FTRButton2.Value = True

'Empty OrderReceivedBox
OrderReceivedBox.Value = ""

'Empty OrderProcessedBox
OrderProcessedBox.Value = ""

'Empty SSDMBox
SSDMBox.Value = ""

'Empty P2PBox
P2PBox.Value = ""

'Empty CustomerBox
CustomerBox.Value = ""

'Empty PMABox
PMABox.Value = ""

'Empty SPBox
SPBox.Value = ""


End Sub
```

The userform itself is called AddRoute55 in the properties. But when I press the command button, I'm seeing error 424, object not found and it refers to the line of AddRoute55.Show. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format the code of your sub as code via editing your post. You can do so by marking your code and clicking on the curly braces.

Comment: Can't try at the moment but this might work: `VBA.UserForms.Add("AddRoute55").Show`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, that this is the name and not the caption?

If your code doesn't work, try this:

```
Private Sub Route55Button_Click()    
     UserForm1.Show    
End Sub
```

You can change the `name` of your Userform by right-clicking on your Userform in the VBA-Editor in Design Mode.

Comment: Yep..Changed the name in the top field op the properties. I can send you a download link to the file if you like, maybe you can see what is wrong with settings..